# How to import pjsip library in Android

Tags: android, swig, pjsip, android-ndk-r7

I am developing the app in Windows with the following Architecture.
Android - API19
Eclipse  - Juno
OS -Windowsx64

Can anybody help me how to import the PJSIP library? I want to develop an SIP to SIP call application.

Comment: Anyone kindly share the knowledge in this.

Answer (score 0):

the [getting started](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android) guide only provide instructions using linux.

you can install cygwin/mingw and try to continue to build in windows

or just create a vm using virtualbox/vmware, install linux then develop on it.